# How to retrieving page info using app access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

When I am requesting using this request-

$accessToken = $jsHelper->getAccessToken($facebookClient);
$userAccessToken = $accessToken->getValue();
$longlivedtoken = $fb->get("/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=" . env('FACEBOOK_APP_ID') . "&client_secret=" . env('FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY') . "&fb_exchange_token=" . $userAccessToken, $userAccessToken);

$response = $longlivedtoken->getDecodedBody();
$useraccesstoken = $response['access_token'];

```
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,accounts', $useraccesstoken)
using php SDK , Then getting is error:-

"message" => "An unknown error occurred",
"type" => "OAuthException",

"is_transient" => false
"error_user_title" => "Exceeded asset access limit"
"error_user_msg" => "You have exceeded asset access limit for the calling user. For asset type page, there is a limit to 3 instances the app can access for the caller."
```

code is 1 and error subcode is 1349193,

When this same code is running in Development mode is working fine but Now working in live mode then getting this problem:
Please check this app review SS: https://prnt.sc/lxt3ei

Comment: Please add tag `facebook`. And go through documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting/

Comment: "using app access token" - are you sure about that? what is $useraccesstoken? hopefully NOT an app access token, but a user token with the neccessary permissions?

Comment: This same code was working before but now I have submitted new another app for review and got approved. and when I am using this app id and secret gettting this message

Comment: First using this request
$longlivedtoken = $fb->get("/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=" . env('FACEBOOK_APP_ID') . "&client_secret=" . env('FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY') . "&fb_exchange_token=" . $userAccessToken, $userAccessToken);

Comment: $response = $longlivedtoken->getDecodedBody();
 $useraccesstoken = $response['access_token'];
this $useraccesstoken is using with this request
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,accounts', $useraccesstoken);
but getting the given above errors

Comment: Please help me,
Thank  you
Shankar